# ReactJS vs NodeJS - Why do I need to create both?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I understand that React is frontend, and NodeJS is the backend that allows Javascript code to function outside of a browser. What I don't understand (and this is after following tutorials online on setting up a React project and a NodeJS project) is why I have to create an instance of each.

For example, in my React project, I managed to create a website. But because I needed a backend, I decided to use NodeJS. But I'm doing NodeJS tutorials, and I can create a website using NodeJS too. I'm confused because right now, it's appearing to be that React and NodeJS do the *SAME THING*.

I have never worked with NodeJS before so I am a bit confused. I was under the impression that I would just use NodeJS to host the backend, but after seeing that I'm literally having to create an entire website with NodeJS, I don't understand how I'm supposed to use React and NodeJS together.

How do the two, React and NodeJS, integrate together to create a fully-functioning web app? I have yet to see something online that clearly breaks down how the two interact.

Comment: Most React frontend project uses NodeJS as a way to run scripts (even third-party modules) that serve as tools for development. These scripts could be in any other languages, but since the developer is already writing JavaScript to build a React app, it makes sense to use tools from the same ecosystem.

Comment: Same answer.  Just because you have a React frontend does not mean you **must** have a node backend, or vise versa.  Any frontend framework can be paired with any backend.

Comment: Not sure if this is good anatomy but, If ReactJS was food, and Browser was a frying pan then NodeJS would be fuel which would serve heat to your browser. You can replace fuel with any source however.

Comment: you can use react as full front stuck then your nodejs will be a full API services or you can integrate react  progressively to use some components for example in some views rendered with template engine

Comment: Node frameworks such as Express are commonly used to render views/templates, but it does not need to necessarily. It can act entirely as a RESTful API to perform remote CRUD actions via HTTP calls from React.

Comment: I followed some NodeJS tutorials, and we created a web app. It looks like one could build the front end in NodeJS, too. It looks like NodeJS has front end capabilities as well as being a backend technology. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: A NodeJS backend server _could_ definitely return HTML as response content to HTTP requests. Which would then make it a full website on its own. Though, all the JavaScript would run on the server instead of the client's browser.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky That is what I want to do. Maybe I am just looking at the wrong places and it was confusing me. Is this what I want? -> http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: React uses node, that is why `it's appearing to be that React and NodeJS do the SAME THING.`

Comment: @JessicaWang If you created a project using [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), it has both API routes such as `GET /users` as well as rendered view/templates `index`. You at minimum follow the users route file as an example of creating API endpoints. You can remove anything you don't need. This is kind of a bigger question and would be difficult to explain fully. That being said, that is the correct documentation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

React is front-end library. It provides great tooling for creatiing user interfaces. And it creates a single page application. Which means when you open a react app. It does not reload and its really fast.

While you could also use nodejs and something like handlebars to create a website. But that website would be rendered on server and then served to the user. But its alot more than that. There are a lot of things that you want to do on the server. Like authentication. You want that part to be secure. So you keep it on the server.

Now the answer to the final part of your question.

For a fully functional app. You would use react to create user interfaces. And nodejs for creating an API which your react app will call.

Answer (score 30):

NodeJS is not just regular javascript, it is a javascript runtime that sits on top of a C++ engine called V8, provided by Google. Node executes outside the browser, whereas React / Vue / Angular / etc are in-browser javascript frameworks.

React is a whole separate animal; it is a framework that renders its own DOM in the browser.   It is a javascript engine that is configured to optimize DOM manipulation.

While the development pattern of frontend and backend appear similar, they are doing different things. React is handling component lifecycles, applying dynamic style rules, processing in-browser data, and making API calls. Node is handling requests from the browser, coordinating access to the server's file system, managing network I-O, performing cryptographic evaluation, etc. Because of these different responsibilities, Node makes use of different dependencies (read: node modules) than a frontend framework.

Ultimately, Node and React communicate through HTTP calls (or, less frequently, through a WebSocket or SOAP protocol).

It would behoove you to read about how node works under the hood.

Answer (score 8):

NodeJS is just a runtime that allows you to run javascript code outside of the browser.

In order to compile and transpile the react JS app, they use webpack and other tools which runs over NodeJS.

Comment: You are right, but you only use NodeJS to run the Webpack and Babel (to compile, optimize and transpile). React don't directly depends of nodeJS, but the kit parts involved in the creation process do.

Comment: I was wondering if React itself needs some libraries in node_modules. I like your reply which is concise and gets the points I am looking for. So it appears React doesn't directly need the libraries in node_modules but just node modules are needed during React app build.

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS will serve as your backend, whereas ReactJS will create the interface/UI where you can actually manipulate your server (nodeJS). So first you'll write your NodeJS server or API. You don't **need** to use ReactJS to create a frontend that would interact with your node server, like you said you can use NodeJS to create your views as well through a different library. ReactJS is just one choice of many for the front end of your NodeJS app.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that react and any other SPA library is working on a client-side (browser).

React fetch and consume the data from the server API.

You don't need to use Node.js for building API. You can use various frameworks based on the technology you prefer.

If you are not familiar with the Back End, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server to have a fake API service and can build the Front End part with it.

Answer (score -1):

NodeJS is a javascript framework that allows you to create a server to serve up websites using Express or the built in libraries. It also is capable of building a website with just NodeJS.

You can take advantage of the ability to do server side rendering with a NodeJS server.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

There is a ReactJS framework called NextJS tha has server side rendering of ReactJS component.
https://nextjs.org/#features

You could potentially have some areas of your website that are built solely with NodeJS and other pages that use ReactJS and a NodeJS backend. But it is cleaner to use ReactJS for the front-end and NodeJS for the backend.